# play framework server side processing request is null

Tags: jquery, playframework, datatables

I got a datatable with many rows of entries and wanna make it server side. The problem is that I can't get the `sEcho` as the `request()` is always `null` for me. My code is as follows:

```
    $.fn.loadTable = function (url,options) {

    // check if the options exists or not, defaults to false
    var activity = ((typeof options === "undefined") || (typeof options.activity === "undefined")) ? false : options.activity;
    var document = ((typeof options === "undefined") || (typeof options.document === "undefined")) ? false : options.document;
    var idable   = ((typeof options === "undefined") || (typeof options.idable === "undefined")) ? false : options.idable;

    var element = this;

    var table = element.find("table").dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sZeroRecords": "No data available"
        }
    });     

    $.ajax({
        'url':url,
        dataType:"json",
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data) {                       
            $.each(data,function(index,item) {....
```

And my Controller looks like this:

```
    public static Result getActivitiesByParticipant() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    List<Container> activities = CMISConnection.listActivitiesByParticipant(session("user"));   
            // TODO: change to server side
            // manipulate jsonresult
            ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
            Map<String, String[]> params = request().queryString();
            result.put("sEcho", Integer.valueOf(params.get("sEcho")[0]));
            result.put("iTotalRecords", activities.size());
            result.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", activities.size());

            ArrayNode an = result.putArray("aaData");

            for(Container c : activities) {
              ObjectNode row = Json.newObject();
              row.put("0", c.getName());
              row.put("1", c.getCreator());
              row.put("2", dateFormat.format(c.getCreationDate()));
              row.put("3", c.getOptischerBetreff());
              an.add(row);
            }
    return ok(result);
}
```

`params` is always `null` to me. I configured the route

```
GET     /activity/participant                           controllers.Content.getActivitiesByParticipant()
```

Answer (score 0):

Params is probably null because your url doesn't include a query string. What does the url look like?

[Here](http://feadro.com/play-framework-2-0-datatables-server-side-processing/)'s a comprehensive play 2.0 + datatables example, in case, you haven't come across it before.

Comment: I just call /activity/participant thats my URL. I tried to build that example.

Comment: Perhaps this is obvious but in order for sEcho and other params to be available on the server-side, they need to be included in the url `?sEcho=...&...` Initing your table in the standard datatables way takes care of that for you.                                                                  `$('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/id.php"
} );`

Comment: îf the url is scripts/id.php how do u include sEcho in it? From what I understood sEcho is added automatically to the url and it doesnt have to be added